# Get HTML first sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

How get first sentence from html with image assuming image will be between p tags.
 http://jsfiddle.net/TvyS8/

I need image and first sentence.

I'm thinking about regular expression for image and indexOf for finding symbols of sentence ending. 
Need more opinions, or example how to do it better

I'm getting information via JSON from Tumblr.

Comment: So, in your example, you want `OPS1 continues to improve on its biggest strength: cloud control made easy.` as a result?

Comment: Not exactly, yes i want this sentence and image above this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HW3rT/
.

EDIT:UPDATED FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/2gPXb/

FIDDLE UPDATED

http://jsfiddle.net/XAtcS/

Updated Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/XAtcS/1/

```
var element={};
$('p').each(function(){

if($(this).children().eq(0).prop('tagName')=='IMG' && $(this).next().children().eq(0).prop('tagName')!='IMG')
{
element.first=$(this).html()+$(this).next().html();
}
})
document.write(element.first)
```

Ii will take first p text which does not contain img tag

Comment: I need image and first sentence.

Comment: Doesn't work... The result should be Image and sentence above image "OPS1 continues to improve on its biggest strength: cloud control made easy."

Comment: you want image after sentence "OPS1"??

Comment: I see paragraph, but i want only this sentence and image. "OPS1 continues to improve on its biggest strength: cloud control made easy."

Comment: Thanks, found my on the track. Thanks again man! And updated fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/XAtcS/2/